# Make account pages with unique links in Next JS

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js

So I've been trying to make a website that would include user pages that displays their posts and other info. I'm not sure how to create new links to their accounts. For example, if a user had a UID of 121212, you could access his account information at https://www.example.com/users/121212/. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to create new file in `pages/users/[UID].js` file.

Comment: you can get the user id and fetch the result of the user and send as a props. you may use getserverstateprops method of next js.

Comment: What did you try? What is the coding issue? Post it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create new file in `pages/users/[UID].js`.

When `https://www.example.com/users/121212/`visit this url `pages/users/[UID].js` this file call.

When `https://www.example.com/users/{anotherId}` visit the url also `pages/users/[UID].js` this file call.

In `users` page code

```
import Link from 'next/link'

function Users() {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link href="/Users/abc">
          <a>Go to pages/post/[pid].js</a>
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link href="/Users/abc?foo=bar">
          <a>Also goes to pages/post/[pid].js</a>
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  )
}

export default Users
```

And in `users/[UID].js` file;

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

    const Post = () => {
      const router = useRouter()
      const { UID} = router.query
    
      return <p>Post: {UID}</p>
    }
    
    export default Post
```

For more help [dynamic-routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)

Comment: How would I go about fetching the UID passed through the URL?

Comment: The following code snippet should help you, 

import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const { query } = useRouter();
const { UID } = query;

Comment: @mythic lisp I update my answer check !

Comment: Thanks very much I have it working now